# MateralizeCSS is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have been trying to use [MateralizeCSS](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html); only designed and created by Google; as an alternative for [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as a test and to see the differences by myself. However there is something that is weird with Materalize. The [HTML Setup](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html#setup) stated on their official website is simple, but when I try to resize the window and press the hamburger icon nothing happens. This means that the JavaScript is not loaded correctly, but it's actually included in my HTML file. First I tried to use the CDNs and it's not working. So I decided to download the files and link them in the file, but it's still not working.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="gr__materializecss_com">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Materialize Template</title>

    <!-- Import Google Icon Font -->
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="light-green">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Brand</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="nav-mobile">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Import jQuery before materialize.js -->
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    -->

</body>

</html>
```

I opened the Inspector to see the [Starter Template](http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html) structure for the navbar and it's the same as mine. I can't figure out the problem. So any logical explanation is appreciated.

Comment: you didn't include the code for the sidenav http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js

Comment: @karthick my bad!

Comment: Just a nitpick: Materialize is not owned or officially supported by Google. Google owns Material Design (the design language), but Materialize is just an unofficial project that uses Material Design.

Comment: @sbking Great, thanks a lot for the tip. I really didn't know. Thanks again :) (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize the jQuery plugin for the sideNav method to work. Hope this helps!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Materialize Template</title>

    <!-- Import Google Icon Font -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="light-green">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Brand</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="nav-mobile">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```